# code doesn't throw error but doesn't launch in python or ahk. Where is the error?

Tags: python, autohotkey

I'm new to coding with autohotkey commands within python.  I've successfully written code that doesn't throw an error but the code won't launch through either the python terminal or autohotkey.  The code is below:

```
ctypes = import ctypes

ctypes1 = from ctypes import *

ahk = AHk(executable_path='C:\Users\\bryan\\Downloads\\ahkdll-v2-release-master\\x64w_MT\\AutoHotkey.dll')
dllpath =('C:\Users\\bryan\\Downloads\\ahkdll-v2-release-master\\x64w_MT\\AutoHotkey.dll')
DllCall("LoadLibrary","Str","C:\Users\\bryan\\Downloads\\ahkdll-v2-release-master\\x64w_MT\\AutoHotkey.dll")
DllCall("C:\Users\\bryan\\Downloads\\ahkdll-v2-release-master\\x64w_MT\\AutoHotkey.dll","Str",A_ScriptDir "\MyDllScript.ahk","Str","","CDecl")
While DllCall("C:\Users\\bryan\\Downloads\\ahkdll-v2-release-master\\x64w_MT\\AutoHotkey.dll" "\ahkReady")
```

------->  dll:=AhkThread("C:\Users\bryan\Downloads\scratch_9.ahk" "\MyDllScript.ahk","",true)
      Sleep 100 ; wait for the thread to exit

```
parser = ahk

ahk.key_press(ahk.key_press("^+c", print, ahk.key_press("f + enter")))

ahk.key_press(ahk.key_press("^+z", print, ahk.key_press("u + enter")))

ahk.key_press(ahk.key_press("^+x", print, ahk.key_press("m + enter")))
```

I know it's usually a small error but I'm new at this kind of code so I can't see it.  What am I doing wrong?  Thanks for your help.

Comment: What is the error you're getting?  What's going on at the top of your code...with that **py =** and code inside parentheses.  Last I checked, that wasn't valid Python syntax.

Comment: There isn't an error thrown.  how should the code adding the ctypes be added to the code.  That might be the issue.

Comment: Doh!  You say right in the subject that no error is thrown.  Sorry.  - Does that code at the top compile?  Is this not strictly just Python code?  Is that some Python 3 thing I don't know about?  I'm just not at all familiar with that code construct, and my IDE doesn't like it, even when I switch to Python 3.

Comment: But now it throws an error at line 10.....call to non-existance function.  I edited the post with the current version.  The arrow is where it appears the error is.  Thanks for your help.  It's trying to use autohotkey dll library.

Comment: Now I'm really confused.  That line with the arrow isn't Python.  ":="?  No comma between two string constants?  Backslash in front of 'M'?  "Sleep 100 ; wait for the thread to exit"?